# Shieldgate - Tied Village Clusters

Tags: untagged

In Cartographers, what would score if your 1st and 2nd Village clusters are the same size? There's also a 3rd village cluster at a different size.

The card states:

> Earn two reputation stars for each village space in the second largest cluster of village spaces.

[image]

Comment: If you have three clusters A:8. B:8 and C:3, the size of the second largest cluster is "B", and the second largest cluster size is 3. The former wording is used here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered here:
https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2248798/shieldgate-question

> > What is the correct way to score Shieldgate when you have three villages of size say 8, 8, and 3. Is one of the eights your second largest or are they both the largest and you score the three?
>
> 8 would be your second largest.

This was confirmed in the thread by Keith Matejka of Thunderworks Games.